# Java Jersey RestAPI to retrieve XML from input call

Tags: java, xml, input, jersey

I have to design a Jersey RestAPI where user will post xml as part of the call using application/xml . For example , the RestAPI url of my site will be `http://<mysite>/company/employee` which user will call from their webservice along with a xml which will come as `application/xml`

Can someone please let me know how to read this xml from my Jersey RestAPI code . I understand I have to use `@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XHTML_XML)` . But not sure how to retrieve the xml from input .

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. "Consume" your payload as a String, and parse it using a [DOM Parser](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/), or by invoking a deserialiser such as [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml). This is less recommended, although totally possible.

   ```
   @Path("employee")
   @POST
   @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
   public Response postEmployee(String empXmlString) {

       // DO SOMETHING WITH THE XML (empString)...

       System.out.println(empString);        
       return Response.ok().build();
   }
   ```
2. Use a [JAX-RS Entity Provider](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#d0e6478).

   For an XML payload such as:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <employee>
       <name>Riker</name>
       <id>2</id>
       <rank>Vice manager</rank>
   </employee>
   ```

   Use something like that:

   ```
   @Path("employee")
   @POST
   @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
   @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
   public Response postEmployee(Employee emp) {

       String empDetails = String.format("Entity - name: %s, id: %d, rank: %s", emp.name, emp.id, emp.rank);
       System.out.println(empDetails);

       return Response.ok().entity(empDetails).build();
   }

   @XmlRootElement
   public class Employee {

       @XmlElement public String name;
       @XmlElement public int id;
       @XmlElement public String rank;

       public Employee(String name, int id, String rank) {
           this.name = name;
           this.id = id;
           this.rank = rank;
       }

       public Employee() {
       }
   }
   ```

Note:

- You can use a custom Entity Provider. Check out the *MessageBodyReader* in the Jersey documentation.
- The [Jersey user guide](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/user-guide.html) is really great, use it.
- Read [chapter 9 in the guide](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#xml) - regarding Jersey's serialisation support/plug-ins ("Features").
- Jersey has [very good examples](https://github.com/jersey/jersey). Refer to the [jaxb example](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/tree/master/examples/jaxb), it will be a very good starting point for you.

Comment: Thanks Ido . The first example has worked well . If the xml is something like <?xml version="1.0"?>
<employee>
    <name>Riker</name>
    <id>2</id>
    <rank>Vice manager</rank>
</employee>

Comment: If the xml is something like <?xml version="1.0"?>
<employee>
   <name>Riker</name>
   <contact>
      <mobile>898989</mobile>
      <email>test@xyz.com</email>
   </contact>
    <id>2</id>
    <rank>Vice manager</rank>
</employee> then how to point to Contact ? Should it be @XmlElement ? If so then how should we point to mobile and email tags ?

Comment: Create a Contact class with email and mobile annotated by "@XmlElement". Add a reference to it from the Employee class, annotated by "@XmlElement".

Comment: Check out JAXB guides/examples.

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JAXB/article.html
https://javaee.github.io/jaxb-v2/doc/user-guide/ch03.html

Comment: Thanks Ido for your help